# Highchart-export-server not showing plot band correctly on chart

Tags: highcharts

Plot bands in highchart export server is not working properly. I want the output same as shown in jsfiddle below.
I want the color plot band to show on y axis with width 20.

This is expected output: https://jsfiddle.net/vc6r8y3n/
Attached image is actual output when we use high-chart export server.

but when I tried same JavaScript json object on
http://export.highcharts.com/
its giving me image with plot band color spread on whole chart. its not considering width for 'y' or 'x' axis in export server. I gave attached image of export chart.

Why highchart behaving differently in both the cases.

Highchart JSON is same as in JSfiddle.

Actual image.
Expected is what it display in Jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vc6r8y3n/

```js
{
"chart": {
"height": 350,
"width": 600,
"style": {
"fontFamily": "\"Arial\", sans-serif",
"fontSize": "16px"
},
"backgroundColor": "transparent"
},
"title": {
"text": null
},
"credits": {
"enabled": false
},
"legend": {
"align": "center",
"layout": "horizontal",
"verticalAlign": "bottom",
"symbolHeight": 5,
"symbolWidth": 5,
"symbolRadius": 0,
"itemDistance": 10,
"itemStyle": {
"fontSize": "5px",
"fontWeight": "bold",
"fontFamily": "\"Arial\", sans-serif"
},
"borderWidth": 0,
"padding": 0,
"margin": 5
},
"xAxis": {
"categories": [
"Sep-2020",
"Oct-2020",
"Nov-2020",
"Dec-2020",
"Jan-2021",
"Feb-2021"
],
"labels": {
"style": {
"fontSize": "4px",
"fontFamily": "\"Arial\", sans-serif",
"color": "#000"
},
"y": 5
},
"gridLineColor": "transparent",
"gridLineWidth": 0,
"minorGridLineWidth": 0,
"lineColor": "#9A9A9A",
"zIndex": 9999999
},
"yAxis": [
{
"title": {
"text": ""
},
"min": 0,
"max": 100,
"tickInterval": 20,
"plotBands": [
{
"color": "rgb(204,0,0)",
"from": 0,
"to": 30.99,
"zIndex": 3
},
{
"color": "rgb(226,113,113)",
"from": 31,
"to": 44.99,
"zIndex": 3
},
{
"color": "rgb(247,209,34)",
"from": 45,
"to": 54.99,
"zIndex": 3
},
{
"color": "rgb(136,207,136)",
"from": 55,
"to": 68.99,
"zIndex": 3
},
{
"color": "rgb(68,180,68)",
"from": 69,
"to": 87.99,
"zIndex": 3
},
{
"color": "rgb(0,153,0)",
"from": 88,
"to": 100,
"zIndex": 3
}
],
"width": 20
}
],
"plotOptions": {
"column": {
"dataLabels": {
"enabled": true
}
}
},
"series": [
{
"name": "Line1",
"type": "column",
"data": [
{
"y": 61,
"color": "#5b9bd5"
},
{
"y": 41,
"color": "#5b9bd5"
},
{
"y": 21,
"color": "#5b9bd5"
},
{
"y": 81,
"color": "#5b9bd5"
},
{
"y": 31,
"color": "#5b9bd5"
},
{
"y": 71,
"color": "#5b9bd5"
}
],
"color": "#5b9bd5",
"showInLegend": true
},
{
"name": "Line 2",
"type": "column",
"data": [
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
1
],
"color": "#00B050"
},
{
"name": "Line 3",
"type": "spline",
"data": [
null,
{
"y": 45
},
{
"y": 38
},
{
"y": 32
},
{
"y": 40
},
{
"y": 48
}
],
"color": "#9A0229"
}
]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgXba.png)

Comment: Actual is attached and expected in show in in Jsfiddle.

Comment: When exporting via node module it works fine:
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#using-as-a-nodejs-module

Sending it directly can cause problems because the axes are in arrays and can misinterpret them. This would need to be debugged and possibly fixed so you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/new